# CPU fan randomly going to 100%

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, asus-laptop

I have a problem with cpu fan on my ASUS UX330U. It would completely out of the blue reach max rpm (~8000), even though the system is not loaded at all (like 1-10% cpu usage and around 25-40C temp), while when it's really loaded it never exceeds 6000 rpm. And so 2-20 minutes later (it varies) it goes back to its normal speed  (~3600rpm) in the same random fashion.

In addition to that, so far I have not found a single way to stop this type of behavior, what I mean by that is the problem persists even after I completely shut down my laptop and leave it alone for 30 minutes, even after trying to manually set battery mode to limit the fan activity.

Moreover, I am asking this question 2 days after getting my laptop back from service center, where they changed the motherboard. Today the problem emerged again.
Do you have any suggestions on what that may be?

Comment: Complained to the service center yet? If it wasn't doing that before, and the temps & cpu usage really are staying low & no program is speeding up the fan, then it sounds like something's wrong